# How do I turn extracted data from array to useable numbers in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, text-files

So I got a function that extracts data from a txt document which returns three different arrays.

```
def extract_data(filename):
    infile= open('approx_derivative_sine.txt', 'r')
    dx = []
    abserror = []
    n = []
    
    for line in infile:
        words=line.split()
        #words[0]: delta_x, words[1]: value for delta_x
        dx.append(words[1])
        abserror.append(words[7])
        n.append(words[10])
        
    delta_x=np.array(dx)
    abs_error=np.array(abserror)
    n_array=np.array(n)
    
    return delta_x,abs_error,n_array

infile = open('approx_derivative_sine.txt', 'r')

result=extract_data(infile)

print(result)
```

Now this is the print:

```
(array(['1.000000e-01,', '1.000000e-02,', '1.000000e-03,', '1.000000e-04,',
       '1.000000e-05,', '1.000000e-06,', '1.000000e-07,', '1.000000e-08,',
       '1.000000e-09,', '1.000000e-10,', '1.000000e-11,', '1.000000e-12,',
       '1.000000e-13,', '1.000000e-14,', '1.000000e-15,', '1.000000e-16,',
       '1.000000e-17,', '1.000000e-18,', '1.000000e-19,'], dtype='<U13'), array(['4.409811e-02,', '4.338424e-03,', '4.330960e-04,', '4.330210e-05,',
       '4.330133e-06,', '4.330281e-07,', '4.300676e-08,', '3.038736e-09,',
       '4.137019e-08,', '4.137019e-08,', '4.137019e-08,', '4.445029e-05,',
       '3.996389e-04,', '3.996389e-04,', '5.511151e-02,', '5.000000e-01,',
       '5.000000e-01,', '5.000000e-01,', '5.000000e-01,'], dtype='<U13'), array(['n=1', 'n=2', 'n=3', 'n=4', 'n=5', 'n=6', 'n=7', 'n=8', 'n=9',
       'n=10', 'n=11', 'n=12', 'n=13', 'n=14', 'n=15', 'n=16', 'n=17',
       'n=18', 'n=19'], dtype='<U4'))
```

As you can see the arrays are quite useless, can't really do much with them. How would I turn this into just numbers that I can use to plot in a graph for instance? How do I pick each array and define it as one out of the returned arrays from the function? for example the first array, how do I define it as for example x and the second one as y?

So what I need help with here is how to convert the array strings to usable floats and then define each array so i can use them as values for plotting in a graph. Anyone got any ideas on how I could do so?

Comment: Try `np.array(dx, float)`, to force conversion of the string values to float.  It won't work with the `n` list, but the other 2 should convert.  `result` is a tuple of array, which is to be expected from the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the problem, you want `delta_x,abs_error,n_array` individually so as to plot later. You can try one of the few things,

1: Unpack array on call:

```
delta_x,abs_error,n_array = extract_data(infile)
```

2: Array slicing:

```
result=extract_data(infile)
delta_x,abs_error,n_array = result[:,0], result[:,1], result[:,2]
```

That way you can split the array later.